# What's wrong with this PHP code on Line 136

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I get the following error on my WP Dashboard:

```
Warning: First parameter must either be an object or the name of an existing class 
in /home/content/88/11746388/html/wp-content/plugins/pluginname/pluginname.php on 
line 136
```

Those are my lines from 130 to 140. Any ideas?

```
function get_latest_version($plugin_file) {

    $latest_version = '';

    $sr_plugin_info = get_site_transient ( 'update_plugins' );
    // if ( property_exists($sr_plugin_info, 'response [$plugin_file]') && property_exists('response [$plugin_file]', 'new_version') ) {
    if ( property_exists($sr_plugin_info, 'response [$plugin_file]') ) {
        $latest_version = $sr_plugin_info->response [$plugin_file]->new_version;    
    }
    return $latest_version;
}
```

Comment: What does get_site_transient return?

Comment: If you want 'response [$plugin_file]' to translate the variable in to it's value you need double quotes instead of single quotes

Comment: $sr_plugin_info must be a Object or an existing class name as it written..

Comment: change this line from single quotes to double quotes e.g. `property_exists($sr_plugin_info, "response [$plugin_file]")`

Comment: A property, which name is `response [$plugin_file]` does not equals to an array property, which name is `response` & has an element under index `$plugin_file`

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you have error in this line :

```
if ( property_exists($sr_plugin_info, 'response [$plugin_file]') ) {
```

[property_exists](https://www.php.net/property_exists) — Checks if the object or class has a property .

and `'response [$plugin_file]'` it is not a valid property name of class.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest that code is bleeding from several wounds.

a.) get_site_transient is not guaranteed to return an object and property_exists expects one

b.) you try to check if an array key exists in a property with property_exists. I'm fairly certain that property_exists can not do that - you should only check for `response` property with it and use `isset()` for the `$plugin_file` index.

Comment: This is working with early version PHP. In the old time, you can use property_exists to check a object's key exist or not.

Answer (score -3):

```
function get_latest_version($plugin_file) {

    $latest_version = '';

    $sr_plugin_info = get_site_transient ( 'update_plugins' );
    // if ( property_exists($sr_plugin_info, response[$plugin_file]) && property_exists(response[$plugin_file], 'new_version') ) {
    if ( property_exists($sr_plugin_info, response[$plugin_file]) ) {
        $latest_version = $sr_plugin_info->response[$plugin_file]->new_version;    
    }
    return $latest_version;
}
```

Comment: Simply removing a pair of aphostrophes does not fix anything. This answer results in syntactically wrong code.

Comment: None of the answers that you guys provided did work. Appreciate the effort though :)